# Swift: Recursively cycle through all subviews to find a specific class and append to an array

Tags: arrays, swift, recursion, uiview

Having a devil of a time trying to figure this out. I asked a similar question here: [Swift: Get all subviews of a specific type and add to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151637/swift-get-all-subviews-of-a-specific-type-and-add-to-an-array)

While this works, I realized there are many subviews and sub-sub views, and so I need a function that starts at the main UIView, cycles through all the subviews (and their subviews until there aren't any left) and adds it to an array for a custom button class which I have named CheckCircle.

Essentially I'd like to end up with an array of CheckCircles which constitute all the CheckCircles added to that view programmatically.

Any ideas? Here's what I've been working on. It doesn't seem to be appending any Checkcircles to the array:

```
    func getSubviewsOfView(v:UIView) -> [CheckCircle] {
        var circleArray = [CheckCircle]()
        // Get the subviews of the view

        var subviews = v.subviews

        if subviews.count == 0 {
            return circleArray
        }

        for subview : AnyObject in subviews{
  if let viewToAppend = subview as? CheckCircle {
        circleArray.append(viewToAppend as CheckCircle)
      }
            getSubviewsOfView(subview as! UIView)
        }
        return circleArray
    }
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Edited with what I've cobbled together.

Comment: @KenjiCrosland In each recursive call you're setting a new `circleArray` variable are you aware of this? It's a really bad practice

Comment: Wasn't aware. I'll do my best to avoid.

Comment: @VictorSigler I'm not sure it really matters here since subviews don't typically go more than few levels deep.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, but the mistake was not concatenate the recursive call with the previous `circleArray` like in your answer using the `+=` operator, it was the main problem of the above code, because every result was wasted in each call to the function.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your main problem is that when you call `getSubviewsOfView(subview as! UIView)` (recursively, within the function), you aren't doing anything with the result.

You also can delete the `count == 0` check, since in that case the `for…in` loop will just be skipped. You also have a bunch of unnecessary casts

Assuming your desire is to get a flat array of `CheckCircle` instances, I think this adaptation of your code should work:

```
func getSubviewsOfView(v:UIView) -> [CheckCircle] {
    var circleArray = [CheckCircle]()

    for subview in v.subviews as! [UIView] {
        circleArray += getSubviewsOfView(subview)

        if subview is CheckCircle {
            circleArray.append(subview as! CheckCircle)
        }
    }

    return circleArray
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I decided to change one small part:  if let viewToAppend = subview as? CheckCircle {
        circleArray.append(viewToAppend as CheckCircle)
      }

Comment: @KenjiCrosland If you want to do that, I'd just do `if let subview = subview as? CheckCircle` and `append(subview)`. No need to rename it or cast inside the `if let` scope.

Answer (score 44):

> Based on **Aaron Brager** and **ullstrm** answers

### Details

- Xcode 9.1, Swift 4,
- Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8), Swift 5

### Solution

```
extension UIView {

    class func getAllSubviews<T: UIView>(from parenView: UIView) -> [T] {
        return parenView.subviews.flatMap { subView -> [T] in
            var result = getAllSubviews(from: subView) as [T]
            if let view = subView as? T { result.append(view) }
            return result
        }
    }

    class func getAllSubviews(from parenView: UIView, types: [UIView.Type]) -> [UIView] {
        return parenView.subviews.flatMap { subView -> [UIView] in
            var result = getAllSubviews(from: subView) as [UIView]
            for type in types {
                if subView.classForCoder == type {
                    result.append(subView)
                    return result
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    }

    func getAllSubviews<T: UIView>() -> [T] { return UIView.getAllSubviews(from: self) as [T] }
    func get<T: UIView>(all type: T.Type) -> [T] { return UIView.getAllSubviews(from: self) as [T] }
    func get(all types: [UIView.Type]) -> [UIView] { return UIView.getAllSubviews(from: self, types: types) }
}
```

### Usage sample

```
var allViews = UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView)
func printResult(with text: String) {
    print("\n==============================================")
    print("\(text):\n\(allViews.map { $0.classForCoder } )")
}
printResult(with: "UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView)")

allViews = UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView) as [UILabel]
printResult(with: "UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView) as [UILabel]")

allViews = UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView, types: [UIStackView.self, UILabel.self])
printResult(with: "UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView, types: [UIStackView.self, UILabel.self])")

allViews = simpleView.getAllSubviews()
printResult(with: "simpleView.getAllSubviews()")

allViews = simpleView.getAllSubviews() as [UILabel]
printResult(with: "simpleView.getAllSubviews() as [UILabel]")

allViews = simpleView.get(all: UILabel.self)
printResult(with: "simpleView.get(all: UILabel.self)")

allViews = simpleView.get(all: [UIStackView.self, UILabel.self])
printResult(with: "simpleView.get(all: [UIStackView.self, UILabel.self])")
```

### Output of the sample

```
==============================================
UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView):
[UILabel, UIButton, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UIStackView]

==============================================
UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView) as [UILabel]:
[UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel]

==============================================
UIView.getAllSubviews(from: simpleView, types: [UIStackView.self, UILabel.self]):
[UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UIStackView]

==============================================
simpleView.getAllSubviews():
[UILabel, UIButton, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UIStackView]

==============================================
simpleView.getAllSubviews() as [UILabel]:
[UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel]

==============================================
simpleView.get(all: UILabel.self):
[UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel]

==============================================
simpleView.get(all: [UIStackView.self, UILabel.self]):
[UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UILabel, UIStackView]
```

### Storyboard of the sample

[image]

### Other info

Also, I suggest to work with weak references. [Array with weak references to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47463093/4488252)

Comment: Best answer with great usage of generics!

Comment: This is epic. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

You can implement it simply by extending UIView and defining the following functions.

Swift4 Code

```
extension UIView {
    func findViews<T: UIView>(subclassOf: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return recursiveSubviews.compactMap { $0 as? T }
    }

    var recursiveSubviews: [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap { $0.recursiveSubviews }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
findViews(subclassOf: UILabel.self)
findViews(subclassOf: CheckCircle.self)
```

Answer (score 19):

My approach with swift 3 and generics!

```
private func getSubviewsOf<T: UIView>(view: UIView) -> [T] {
    var subviews = [T]()

    for subview in view.subviews {
        subviews += getSubviewsOf(view: subview) as [T]

        if let subview = subview as? T {
            subviews.append(subview)
        }
    }

    return subviews
}
```

To fetch all UILabel's in a view hierarchy, just do this:

```
let allLabels: [UILabel] = getSubviewsOf(view: theView)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Based on **Vasily Bodnarchuk**'s, **Aaron Brager**'s, and **ullstrm**'s answers.

### Why another one?

I personally do not like to have `as [XXX]` and `let specific: [Type]`, all over but rather pass the type into function calls, e.g.

```
let scrollViews = view.getNestedSubviews(ofType: UIScrollView.self)
print(scrollViews) // outputs: [UIScrollView]
```

I also renamed `All` to `Nested` because it conveys the recursive nature of the function to the API caller better.

### Details

Swift 4.x, Xcode 9.1+

### Solution

```
extension UIView {

    class func getNestedSubviews<T: UIView>(view: UIView) -> [T] {
        return view.subviews.flatMap { subView -> [T] in
            var result = getNestedSubviews(view: subView) as [T]
            if let view = subView as? T {
                result.append(view)
            }
            return result
        }
    }

    func getNestedSubviews<T: UIView>() -> [T] {
        return UIView.getNestedSubviews(view: self) as [T]
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let scrollViews = view.getNestedSubviews(ofType: UIScrollView.self)
print(scrollViews) // outputs: [UIScrollView]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Find (private) Subviews By String:

I would like to add the possibility of detecting even private classes, hidden by Apple from us developers, in general finding classes by a given string:

```swift
func recursiveSubviews() -> [UIView] {

    if subviews.isEmpty {
        return subviews
    }
    return subviews + subviews.flatMap { $0.recursiveSubviews() }
}

func recursiveSubviews(className: String) -> [UIView] {
    let all = recursiveSubviews()
    let filtered = all.filter {
        String(describing: type(of: $0)) == className
    }
    return filtered
}
```

Now you can run:

```swift
activeWindow.recursiveSubviews(className: "_UIContextMenuContainerView")
```

Answer (score -1):

the UITextField is no longer on the top layer of subviews, so I use this method:

```
@implementation UISearchBar (changeFont)

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font {
    for (UIView *v in [self subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)v;
            tf.font = font;
            UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[tf valueForKey:@"placeholderLabel"];
            l.font = font;
            break;
        } else if (v.subviews.count) {
            for (UIView *v1 in v.subviews) {
                if ([v1 isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)v1;
                    tf.font = font;
                    UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[tf valueForKey:@"placeholderLabel"];
                    l.font = font;
                    break;
                } else if (v1.subviews.count) {
                    for (UIView *v2 in v1.subviews) {
                        if ([v2 isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                            UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)v2;
                            tf.font = font;
                            UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[tf valueForKey:@"placeholderLabel"];
                            l.font = font;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a bit long winded, but should account for the textfield moving deeper in the future