# Wrong tint color for UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol, tintcolor

I am using a UIRefreshControl in my UITableViewController to refresh the content. I use the following code in my `-viewDidLoad` method to add it to my table.

```
UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

//[refresh setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Reloading" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor]}]];

[refresh setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal];
[refresh setTintColor:[UIColor colorFromHex:0xff8900]];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[[refresh layer] setZPosition:-1.0f];

//if (iOS_AT_LEAST(10)) {
//  [self setRefreshControl:refresh];
//} else {
    [self setRefresher:refresh];
    [[self tableView] insertSubview:[self refresher] atIndex:0];
//}
```

I created a category for UIColor so it can accept hex values. I use this in the complete application and on another location I get `#ff8900` back which is correct. But setting the tint color on the UIRefreshControl gives me `#fb6a2e` which is odd. The same happens when I try a default color, for example [UIColor lightGrayColor] gives me another tint than giving the same color to another view.

I have found the following post: [UIRefreshControl tint color doesn't match given color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744522/uirefreshcontrol-tint-color-doesnt-match-given-color). I tried to put it into an animation block and the hack given in the answer, but with no luck.

What do I do wrong here?

Another side question. When setting the attributed title, the spinner has a greater space from the top. If this happens, the title will be below the cell if only one is available. Is there a way to move the string up?

[image]

Comment: This is *really* strange. Did you try adding a View.LayoutIfNeeded(); after all that to make sure the drawing cycle has taken every change into account?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't, but I just tested it without any luck. I also saw another strange thing happens when I don't stop the spinner, push another viewcontroller on top of the current one and go back and in the ```-viewWillAppear:``` method states the spinner has to begin spinning again, the color fades from black to the color. I don't set the color in this method anymore, so it already should be orange.