# Custom Pull up refresh Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pull-to-refresh

Pretty much ive used code like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521796/9610805 into my webview project and it works fine but how do i add my own logo* instead of the default spinning circle?

Comment: Create a custom `UIRefreshControl` subclass. It's a `UIView` so you can override its `drawRect(_:)` method, I'm guessing.

Comment: What kind of animation you want ?

Comment: @Nitish Same spinning affect i just want to add a small logo instead.

Comment: @GuyKogus yeah i thought i would use Cgrectmake but it seems that its been changed in the new swift so ill give drawRect a go, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var refreshImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"))
refreshControl?.insertSubview(refreshImageView, at: 0)
```

If you are willing to go for custom library instead, I would like t5o suggest [**Yalantis PullToMakeSoup**](https://github.com/Yalantis/PullToMakeSoup)

Comment: Cant centre the icon exactly horizontally properly lmao im going to keep trying but it seems to look good and ill add an animation to it.

oh and how do i hide the circle spinning thing that is still there?

Comment: Uhh Never ended up centering it to the middle , right now the image spawns to the top left