# How to change UIReferenceLibraryViewController view dismiss "Done" button to an icon?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there a way to change `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` view's "Done" button? Apparently, nesting the view controller inside another NavigationViewController does not really work (see the last screenshot).

The goal is to replace the done button with an SF symbol

```
let word = "home"
let viewController = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: word)
viewController.title = word
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

present(viewController, animated: true)
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: try to embed it in UINavigationViewController

Comment: but it wont change the actual navbar title. see updated screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hacky approach seems required to achieve what we want to.

1. Get the target navigation bar view, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308437/2226315
2. Add the custom button OR change the title

```
extension UIView {
    func findViews<T: UIView>(subclassOf: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return recursiveSubviews.compactMap { $0 as? T }
    }

    var recursiveSubviews: [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap { $0.recursiveSubviews }
    }
}
```

```
let closeButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(systemName: "xmark"),
    style: .done,
    target: self,
    action: nil
)
            
let arrowButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up"),
    style: .done,
    target: self,
    action: nil
)
            
let word = "home"
let viewController = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: word)
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

let navigationBar = viewController.view.findViews(subclassOf: UINavigationBar.self).first
            
navigationBar!.topItem?.title = word
navigationBar!.items!.first!.setLeftBarButton(closeButtonItem, animated: false)
navigationBar!.items?.first?.rightBarButtonItem? = arrowButtonItem
```

[image]