# Is there a way to tell iOS to update the keyboard appearance within a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I'd like to update the `UIKeyboardAppearance` within a `ViewController`. By this I mean let's say the VC loads with `UIKeyboardAppearance.default`. If I press a button, I'd like the keyboard to update to `.dark` and have the keyboard now show in that same VC as `.dark`.

As far as I can tell, iOS checks the value for `UIKeyboardAppearance` while loading the VC, and doesn't check again until it loads the VC again. Even if you change the value of `UIKeyboardAppearance` and hide/show the keyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// creating a simple text box, and making the placeholder text the value of the keyboardAppearance
        myTextBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        myTextBox.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 200, width: 300, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(myTextBox)
        UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
        myTextBox.becomeFirstResponder()
        myTextBox.placeholder = "Keybaoard Appearance is: \(UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance.rawValue)"

// a simple button to toggle the keyboardAppearance
        toggleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 300, width: 300, height: 50)
        toggleButton.setTitle("Toggle Keyboard", for: .normal)
        toggleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleButtonFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(toggleButton)

    }

// toggles the keyboardAppearance. Hides the keyboard, and a second later shows it again.
    @objc func toggleButtonFunction() {
        if UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance == .dark {
            UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .default
        }
        else {
            UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
        }
        myTextBox.resignFirstResponder()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
            self.myTextBox.becomeFirstResponder()
            self.myTextBox.placeholder = "Keybaoard Appearance is: \(UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance.rawValue)"

            })
    }

    let myTextBox = UITextField()
    let toggleButton = UIButton()
}
```

I was hoping that after changing the `UIKeyboardAppearance` and hiding/showing the keyboard it would show with the new appearance (`.dark` or `.default`), but it continually shows with the same appearance until the VC is loaded again. You can see the value of `UIKeyboardAppearance` changes, but iOS seems to not check for that update until the VC loads again.

Is there any way to force a recheck within a VC?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the keyboard appearance of all text fields recursively on your screen (the `allSubviewsOf(type:)` extension is from [this great answer by Mohammad Sadiq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45297466/3151675)):

```
func changeTextFieldKeyboardAppearance() {
    UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark

    let textFields = view.allSubviewsOf(type: UITextField.self)

    let firstResponder = textFields.first { $0.isFirstResponder }

    firstResponder?.resignFirstResponder()

    textFields.forEach { $0.keyboardAppearance = .dark }

    firstResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
}

[...]

extension UIView {
    func allSubviewsOf<T: UIView>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var all = [T]()

        func getSubview(view: UIView) {
            if let aView = view as? T {
                all.append(aView)
            }

            guard !view.subviews.isEmpty else {
                return
            }

            view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
        }

        getSubview(view: self)

        return all
    }
}
```

If your view controller is embedded in a `UITabBarController`, you can trigger an update by changing its `selectedIndex` and changing it back to the original index immediately:

```
guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else {
    return
}

let selectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex

UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark

tabBarController.selectedIndex = selectedIndex == 1 ? 0 : 1
tabBarController.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tamás for the answer!

It led me down the path to discover what I needed.

It looks like if you change the keyboardAppearance for UITextField

```
UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

the system only checks on VC load. If you change it for each textField

```
myTextBox.keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

the system will check each time firstResponder changes and load the correct keyboard.

Thanks again Tamás!