# Animating UITextView cause text disappeared while animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextview

I am trying to animate UITextView by changing transform. But it makes text disappered while animating. Here is my test code.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let textView = UITextView()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textView)
        
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        textView.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        textView.text = "abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd"
        textView.textColor = .white

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations:  {
                self.textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)
            })
            animator.startAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

I tried with storyboard but the result was same. Same result when I use `UIView.animate` method.

Why does this happen? I want to animate it with text on.

#### UPDATE

```swift
let contraint = textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
contraint.isActive = true

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    contraint.constant = 1000
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations:  {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```

I tested with this code, and got same result.

Comment: @matt I tried to animate top constraint, and got same result. I updated my question.

Comment: Yup I agree. Darn! Okay, I do have one very obvious suggestion: animate a snapshot instead. Sorry, but it might be the best way. I'll whip up an example.

Comment: @matt Yeah. Animating a snapshot works perfect. I tested it before. 

Comment: Gave it as an answer anyway. No bad thing; this is what snapshot views are for, after all, i.e. to give you something to animate.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you'll have to animate a snapshot view instead:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    let v = self.textView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
    v.frame = self.textView.frame
    self.view.addSubview(v)
    self.textView.isHidden = true
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut, animations:  {
        v.frame.origin.y = 1000
    })
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```

I don't think that's a bad solution; this is what snapshot views are for, after all.

Comment: Yeah. This is good. Actually I animate transform during interactive transition. But finding all UITextView subviews of view takes some time, so I want to avoid it.

Comment: Oooooh that sounds like a different question. I actually have a cool utility that will find all UITextView subviews instantly. :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138866/341994 — It sounds to me like you haven't really asked the right question here, though; clearly what you want to do is a lot more interesting than the example you gave. I'm glad you gave the simple example, because you made it really easy to reproduce the issue; but more broadly you evidently want to make text views user-draggable or some such.

Comment: yeah, it's a different question though, I don't know why this simple example doesn't works. 

Comment: File a bug with Apple if you think the text view should keep displaying its text while being animated. But clearly it doesn't, you proved that; so we have to work around it.