# Generic to set placeholder text on only set UILabels

Tags: swift, lifecycle

### The Problem:

I have a large project that has UILabel, TextFields, etc.. that are not currently being set with a placeholder in the event that data is missing. I currently have a constants file with `Constants.placeholder` which returns "`-`". I need a way to reliably set that value on any `UILabel` that is contained in the `UIView`.

### Possible Solutions:

I could create a function that accepts `UIView` then iterates over the subViews replacing any instance of UILabel's text value with `Constants.placeholder` the problem with this solution is that I have some labels that are static, set in interface builder, of which I DON'T want to change those. Similar to this: [Swift: Get all subviews of a specific type and add to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151637/swift-get-all-subviews-of-a-specific-type-and-add-to-an-array)

Another thought I had was to create a function that accepts an array of `[UILabel]` and iterate over those, which could be done and is valid, however it may take quite a bit of work to implement that.

```
func reset(labels: [UILabel]) {
    for label in labels {
        label.text = Constants.placeholder
    }
}
```

My final thought was to somehow intercept `awakeFromNib` and force set the references, but I don't think this is technically feasible. Ultimately I need to set that value, `Constants.placeholder`, anywhere I have a UILabel that is being set, without having to manually do it everywhere.

Comment: Can't you use a `tag` to identify which labels are preset in the storyboard? The tag can be easily set in the storyboard too.

Comment: Unfortunately not, we use tags for accessibility options so that is out of the question. Good thought however.